# Using NSURLConnection With Swift

Tags: swift, nsurl

I am using the following code to get data from an API:

```
typealias JSONdic = [String: AnyObject]

if let json = json as? JSONdic, history = json["history"] as? JSONdic, hour = history["hour"] as? String {
println(hour)
}
```

However, Xcode tells me that "json" is not a recognized identifier. I believe this can be solved with NSURLConnection, but I have no idea how to use that. Can anyone provide any examples of this protocol in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring a variable by setting it to itself, which doesn't make any sense. In order to use a variable on the right hand side of an assignment, it needs to have already been declared. So let's give `json` a value outside of the casting statements and it works fine.

```
typealias JSONdic = [String: AnyObject]

let json: AnyObject = ["greeting": "Hello"]
if let json = json as? JSONdic, history = json["history"] as? JSONdic, hour = history["hour"] as? String {
    println(hour)
}
```

Comment: Could I ask you one more thing? How would I insert the address for an API so that this code would take data from it?

Comment: That's a whole other question :) All the code here is just about parsing JSON data. network connections are a whole other thing. Ask another question focused on that to get more help.